# Insert data using latin-1 encoding

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I need to insert data encoded as latin-1 into a SQLite database. (It's an external requirement; changing the DB or the encoding is not an option.) According to the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) this should be possible:

> SQLite is not particular about the text it receives and is more than happy to process
>   text strings that are not normalized or even well-formed UTF-8 or UTF-16. Thus,
>   programmers who want to store IS08859 data can do so using the UTF-8 interfaces.

I can encode the text easily enough:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
byte[]  data    = mystring.getBytes(charset);
```

but I can't see how to insert it as Statement.executeUpdate expects a String, not a byte array.

Comment: please don't! you'll be sorry at some point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the string into a byte array with the desired encoding and read it back as (malformed) UTF-8 just before running the query.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ...";
// Ugly trickery to insert data encoded as latin-1
query = new String(query.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could pretend that your ISO8859-1 strings are UTF-8 strings, it would be better to store them as blobs.
SQLite will automatically convert between blobs and strings when needed (the internal implementation is identical anyway), and most [internal functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), when executed on a blob instead of a string, will use byte indexes, which is exactly what you want.

Blobs are handled with parameters:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) VALUES(?)");
ps.setBytes(1, data);
ps.execute();
```

Comment: This would require changing the schema, no? That's a non-starter for me, as it's externally defined.

Comment: In SQLite, you can insert blobs into any column without problems; it uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).